# Open Unity Scripting API Reference in Chrome instead of built in Visual Studio browser.

Tags: c#, google-chrome, unity-game-engine, editor

I want Visual Studio 2015 Unity to open Scripting API in Google chrome, because the built in Visual Studio browser is very slow, and every time I click in something Visual Studio freezes for 10 seconds.

How can I open Unity Scripting API Reference in Chrome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1**.Go to *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Tools for Unity* -> *General*

**2**.Now, set *Use external browser* to `true`.

**Done! Test it**

**1**.Select any Unity API you want to open in external browser, go to *Help* -> *Unity API Reference*

**2**.You will see a pop-up Windows Option that will let you chose which program to open that *Unity API Reference* with.

Simply select Chrome. Make sure to also tick the *Always use this app to open .htmls files* box so that it will always open with Chrome.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers to you!!

Comment: Glad you found this to be helpful.

Comment: I've done this in the past and had accidentally set the default app to something else. How can I get it to ask for the default program assignment again?

Comment: @Atlas2k Ask this as a new question then link back to this question. It's a long process.